# Working of Apple Pay in iOS swift

Tags: ios, swift, stripe-payments, applepay

I have integrated the code required for Apple Pay in my app based on the documentation available with Apple.
However, as a beginner, I have a doubt.

We have not used any third party payment processors like PayPal, Stripe etc. 
Is it mandatory to use a third party processors? Can we just use the code and passbook/wallet and do the transactions?

Note: Merchant IDs, Payment certificates are created in the developer account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on Apple [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/apple-pay/get-started/) a payment provider is recommended but not mandatory.

> Using one of these SDKs or hosted solutions is highly recommended

About develop your own payment process...

> The alternative is to provide your own server-side solution to receive
>   payments from your app or website, decrypt payment tokens and
>   interface with the payment provider to process the authorization.
>   Handling credit and debit card payments can be complicated and unless
>   you already have the expertise and systems in place, an Apple Pay SDK
>   or JS API from a payment provider is the quickest and most reliable
>   way to support Apple Pay in your app or website.

In my opinion, It's **better use a payment provider** than develop your own. You're working with money, credit cards numbers...